# columns selected neither in GROUP BY cause or aggregate function?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, group-by

I have a database with `cats`, `toys` and their relationship `cat_toys`

To find the names of the cats with more than 5 toys, i have the following query:

```
select
  cats.name
from
  cats
join
  cat_toys on cats.id = cat_toys.cat_id
group by
  cats.id
having
  count(cat_toys.toy_id) > 7
order by
  cats.name
```

Column `cats.name` does not appear in the `group by` or be used in aggregate function, but this query works. in contrast, I cannot select anything in `cat_toys` table.

Is this something special with psql?

Comment: Please show us the results that you would like to get.

Comment: It works because that's how SQL works. What other answer do you expect? You need to tell us what you expected & why, ie why it wouldn't work & why. With justifcation referring to an authoritative reference, so you might catch your misconceptions & so you have done reasonable research. In code questions give a [mre]. Always read the manual re functionality you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is trying to tell you. It is a general requirement in SQL that you need to list in the `group by` clause all non-aggregaed columns that belong to the `select` clause.

Postgres, unlike most other databases, is a bit more clever about that, and understands the notion of *functionaly-dependent* column: since you are grouping by the primary key of the `cats` table, you are free to add any other column from that table (since they are functionaly dependent on the primary key). This is why your existing query works.

Now if you want to bring values from the `cast_toys` table, it is different. There are potentially multiple rows in this table for each row in `cats`, which, as a consequence, are *not* functionaly dependent on `cats.id`. If you still want one row per cat, you need to make use of an aggregate function.

As an example, this generates a comma-separated list of all `toy_id`s that relate to each cat:

```
select c.name, string_agg(ct.toy_id, ', ') toy_ids
from cats c
inner join cat_toys ct on t.id = ct.cat_id
group by c.id
having count(*) > 7
order by c.name
```

Side notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- for this query, I recommend `count(*)` instead of `count(cat_toys.toy_id)`; this produces the same result (unless you have `null` values in `cat_toys.toy_id`, which seems unlikely here), and incurs less work for the database (since it does not need to check each value in the column against `null`)

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select c.name
from cats c join
     cat_toys ct
     on c.id = ct.cat_id
group by c.id
having count(ct.toy_id) > 7
order by c.name;
```

You are asking why it works:  You are rightly observing that `c.id` is in the `group by` but not in the `select` -- and another column *is* in the `select`.  Seems wrong.  But it isn't.  Postgres supports a little known part of the standard, related to *functional dependency* in aggregation queries.

Let me avoid the technical jargon.  `cats.id` is the primary key of `cats`.  That means the `id` is unique, so knowing the `id` specifies all other columns from `cats`.  The database knows this -- that it, it knows that the value of `name` is always the same for a given `id`.  So, by aggregating on the primary key, you can access the other columns without using aggregation functions -- and it is consistent with the standard.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html):

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or **when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns**, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.